# htaccess 404 error redirect to video

Tags: .htaccess

i have some videos (.m3u8) in a directory
users play them in web or phone players (android,ios,jw web player,web flowplayer-html5)

so sometimes they play files that dont exist  example  123.m3u8 234.m3u8 ...
so is there a way to make a default video so if anyone is playing a file that dont exist then to play default.m3u8

i tryed

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/default.m3u8
```

but when i test on web players it doesnt work 
(u can test here http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/ )

so maybe because it redirect the url from xxxx.m3u8 to default.m3u8 
so is there a way to fix this or maybe a  think a way that will play default.m3u8 but url will be xxxx.m3u8

Answer (score 1):

You can use an absolute path instead of the full url :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /default.m3u8
```

This will not redirect the non-existent request but internally rewrite it to `/default.m3u8` .

Answer (score 0):

Hello code below should help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.m3u8 /path/to/default.m3u8 [NC,L]
```